# How to access a property in .properties file during or before the main() method in Spring?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

We have converted an existing web app over to Spring Boot.

All I want to to do is be able to use @Profile("production").  We store that in myProps.properties in the resources folder.

I can access the .properties file all over the app just fine using @Value, but it seems in order to get the @Profile to work, you have to set the active profiles before the ServletContext is set/final which seems to happen during the main() method.

I've tried dozens of things and failed.  I've found you can't set a static field with @Value in the main application class. I've tried making a class that implements WebApplicationInitializer like https://www.baeldung.com/spring-profiles but my onStartup() method that I override doesn't ever get run.. I put in a break point and it never gets hit.  The only way I can get a break point to hit is if I @Autowire the servletContext on that method, but then the context is already set and cannot be altered.

I've tried AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext, I've tried ServletContainerInitializer, I've tried ConfigurableEnvironment, etc.  I feel like I'm going in circles.

I feel like there is a big piece I'm missing here in order to do things the "Spring way".  Can anyone offer Java annotation-configured way for me to get a property and set the active profiles for using later in the product?  Thanks.

Comment: @Thomas__  the onStartup() in 4.1 in that link never runs for me.  A break point never gets hit.

Comment: What are you trying to achieve with @Profile("production")?

Comment: @ThisIsNoZaku Well some of our webservers will run different Tasks depending on certain properties.  The property is set by our Ops guys in the properties file during the deploy process.. ie outside of the codebase.

Answer (score 0):

Why do you need it before main? Why don't you just create multiple properties files and define the profile in the top-level property file?

(parent) application.properties

```
spring.profiles.active = development-application.properties
```

(profile) development-application.properties

```
my.value = foo
```

Comment: What if 'development-application.properties' has 1000 entries, most of which have nothing to do with profiles?  I could make a 3rd .properties file for the profile stuff maybe, but I was trying to not have to do that.

Answer (score 0):

Based on your comments, I suggest something like the following as a solution:

Define your tasks as beans with `@Component`s and annotate them with `@Profile` to divide them up by the environment you want them to be used in (I prefer setting profiles as environment variables).

```
@Component
@Profile("production")
public class TaskA implements Task {
    public void doWork(){}
}

@Component
@Profile("staging")
public class TaskB implements Task {
    public void doWork(){}
}
```

Marking these classes with `@Component` means Spring will manage them and they can be injected, perhaps into a `@Component` that executes the tasks:

```
@Component
public class TaskDoer {
    private List<Task> tasksToDo;
    @Inject
    public TaskDoer(List<Task> tasksToDo) {
        this.tasksToDo = tasksToDo;
    }
}
```

When deploying your app, set the profile to use in the environment variables in whatever way is appropriate for your setup:

```
SPRING_PROFILES_ACTIVE = production, someOtherProfile
```

Now, when the application starts, Spring will see that the active profiles are "production" and "someOtherProfile" (multiple profiles can be set) and will not load any beans with an `@Profile` that aren't for that profile.

Comment: Thanks for the reply.  "..set the profile to use in the environment variables in whatever way is appropriate for your setup:"= yea, that's the problem.. I have everything else figured out except that part.  We already have a custom setting in a custom .properties file that I was hoping to re-use.  Despite all my efforts listed above, I can't find a way to use those custom properties for this.  I guess we'll just HAVE to do spring.profiles.active in a property file.  :shrug: